# Formatting ROS data to .csv file

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a Rosbag of turtlesim data and would like to export the x and y coordinates only to a .csv file. Right now, however the formatting is as such:

```
x    
y    
x    
y    
x    
y
```

using this command to export to a test .csv file: `rostopic echo /turtle1/pose | sed -n '/x:/,/y:/p' > ~/Desktop/test.csv`

I would like the formatting to be like this:

```
x y
x y
x y
```

Does anyone know how I would do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318393/formatting-ros-data-to-.csv-file/) by [carlito898](https://answers.ros.org/users/40430/carlito898/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way you attempted to produce the desired CSV isn't really a ROS question at all. Rather, that's a Bash/sed question that would be better asked on something like [Super User](https://superuser.com/).  That said, there are several ROS ways that you could likely get what you want.

- The [rosbag api](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) would allow you to easily open the bag file and then save the data you want in whatever your desired format. A Python script to do what you're looking for would only be a few lines
- With a combination of the `-p` and `-b` args to `rostopic echo` you could easily produce a CSV file that included all fields in the topic. Then it would be trivial to extract the columns that you are looking for. See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857090/extract-specific-columns-from-delimited-file-using-awk) for some good examples. I've used `cut` for this purpose many times.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2019-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rostopic echo -p
```

prints you the data in a csv-like manner.

I guess in your case it'd be something like

```
rostopic echo -p /turtle1/pose > ~/Desktop/test.csv
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2019-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think dumping code on Q&A sites is frowned upon, but I came across this trying to implement the Python script below. It exports the joint states from a rosbag to a CSV file. Maybe it will be helpful for someone. Changing the relevant lines to export the poses as requested in the original question should be trivial.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import csv
import math
import rosbag
import rospy
import copy

##################
# DESCRIPTION:
# Creates CSV files of the robot joint states from a rosbag (for visualization with e.g. pybullet)
# 
# USAGE EXAMPLE:
# rosrun your_package get_jstate_csvs.py /root/catkin_ws/bagfiles 20201021_inhand_pose_exp_peg.bag
# ##################

filename = sys.argv[2]
directory = sys.argv[1]
# Read the rosbag file
print("Reading the rosbag file")
if not directory.endswith("/"):
  directory += "/"
extension = ""
if not filename.endswith(".bag"):
  extension = ".bag"
bag = rosbag.Bag(directory + filename + extension)

# Create directory with name filename (without extension)
results_dir = directory + filename[:-4] + "_results"
if not os.path.exists(results_dir):
  os.makedirs(results_dir)

print("Writing robot joint state data")

with open(results_dir +"/"+filename+'_joint_states.csv', mode='w') as data_file:
  data_writer = csv.writer(data_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
  data_writer.writerow(['time', 'robot_elbow_joint', 'robot_shoulder_lift_joint', 
  'robot_shoulder_pan_joint', 'robot_wrist_1_joint', 'robot_wrist_2_joint', 'robot_wrist_3_joint'])
  # Get the joint states
  for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['/joint_states']):
    if msg.name[0] == "robot_elbow_joint":
      p = msg.position
      data_writer.writerow([t, p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]])

print("Finished creating csv file!")
bag.close()
```

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-04**:
Would be great if you could add it to the [wiki/rosbag/Cookbook](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) page.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-11-04**:
Right, why not. I added it.